# Getting an ActionController::UnknownFormat, rspec testing when creating new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Recently moved to Rails 4 and getting errors that I wasn't getting before. 
I'm trying to test a form that I'm making using Capybara/Rspec.

When I click the button on the form, the error I get is:

```
Failure/Error: find(".submit.button").click
     ActionController::UnknownFormat:
       ActionController::UnknownFormat
     # ./app/controllers/office_listings_controller.rb:32:in `create'
     # ./spec/features/office_listings_spec.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It points to my controller which looks like:

```
def create
    selected_amenities = params[:amenities] || [] # empty list if no amenities checked
    @office_listing = OfficeListing.new(params[:office_listing])
    @office_listing.broker = current_broker
    p current_broker
    @office_listing.neighborhood = Neighborhood.find(params[:neighborhood_id])
    p @office_listing.neighborhood
    if @office_listing && @office_listing.save!
      @path = city_neighborhood_office_listing_path(@office_listing, :city_id => @office_listing.neighborhood.city.id, :neighborhood_id => @office_listing.neighborhood.id)
      create_amenities(@office_listing, selected_amenities)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else
      @failure = "Unable to create office :-("
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

and it doesn't like the format.js line 
even though I have a create.js.erb file which is being rendered when I actually run the page.

Don't understand why the actual page is running but my test is failing.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: your test probably runs the create action in html format while your controller runs only in js format.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem:

```
post :duplicate, id: patient.media.first.id
```

produced the same error:

```
Failure/Error: post :duplicate, id: patient.media.first.id
ActionController::UnknownFormat:
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

I fixed it by adding the format to the post call:

```
post :duplicate, id: patient.media.first.id, format: :js
```

Answer (score 3):

Before Rails 5:

```
post :action, id: ..., format: :json
```

From Rails 5 onward:

```
post :action, params: { id: ..., format: :json }
```

Comment: Great answer that I wish I had seen an hour ago. Rails 5 FTW!

Answer (score 2):

yep, using the format: :js solved the problem, in my case my code looks like this:

**In my spec:**

```
  params = {
    profile_id: profile.id,
    track_id: track.id,
    format: :js
  }

  post :create, params
```

**In my controller:**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {}
  end
```